# Is a CEO of a company a de facto public figure?

Tags: corporate-law, libel, slander

In other words, does a CEO share the same protections as a private citizen against slander/libel if the CEO only appears to the public (in interviews, shows, etc.) as a representative of the company instead of for self-aggrandizement?

jurisdiction: US, FL.

Comment: Presumably it depends on the prominence of the company.  Is the CEO of a major international social network service a public figure? Probably. The CEO of your local yard maintenance service, probably not.

Comment: @phoog Even if the CEO of the local yard maintenance service takes part in activities such as interviews?

Comment: I suppose it would depend on the prominence of those interviews.

Answer (score 2):

### Generally, no

A limited purpose public figure must have "thrust themselves to the forefront of particular public controversies in order to influence the resolution of the issues involved" to be a [public figure](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_figure).

Merely being a CEO doesn’t do this. Being a CEO at the heart of controversy like Facebook’s Mark Zuckerberg or Volkswagen’s Martin Winterkorn does.

Comment: Could someone else, say a newspaper, thrust a CEO into a controversy that the CEO wasn't trying to be a part of, and satisfy the definition to what makes a public figure?

Comment: @StephanS yes, people can become public figures involuntarily